# How to bulk rename multiple files with same name and different extensions in python

Tags: python

I have a folder with a thousands of image files and JSON files, how can I bulk rename identical image files and JSON ?

For example

```
image.jpg -> 1.jpg
image.json -> 1.json
```

Here is what I tried which works fine for incremental label, how can I change it to also label files with same names alike ?

```
def renamed_files(path, label):

    i=0

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        try:
            f, extension = os.path.splitext(path+filename)
            src=path+filename
            dst=path+str(i)+extension
            os.rename(src,dst)
            i+=1

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            i+=1

path="C://Users//other_images//"


renamed_files(path)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Generally for coding questions we'd like to see code that you've tried, what didn't work, etc. Could you add some info on what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please provide more context of the question. Two or more files with the same name cannot exist. Is it in the format of Image.jpg, Image1.jpg,Image2.jpg or like image.jpg and image.json with only extension differences

Comment: @High-Octane. Two or more files can exist with the same name, if they had different extensions

Comment: @favoretti my bad, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `sets` to store `jpg` filenames and `json` filesname. Then, take intersection of both sets to take files that have the same name and rename them. The code for the approach is given below.

> How can you change your code to do this?

First, create the two described sets. Now iterate through filenames. If file has extension=='jpg' then check if the filename exists in json_files set. If yes, rename both files, json and jpg. Similarly for file with extension=='json'.

```py
import os
jpg_files = set()
json_files = set()
base_path = './'
for x in os.listdir(base_path):
    name, ext = x.split('.')
    if ext == 'jpg':
        jpg_files.add(name)
    elif ext == 'json':
        json_files.add(name)
counter = 1
for filename in jpg_files.intersection(json_files): # For files that are common (same names)
    os.rename(os.path.join(base_path,filename+'.jpg'),os.path.join(base_path,str(counter)+'.jpg')) # Rename jpg file
    os.rename(os.path.join(base_path,filename+'.json'),os.path.join(base_path,str(counter)+'.json')) # Rename json file
    counter += 1 # Increment counter
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first store identical names with same extensions inside a `collections.defaultdict`, then rename the groups with more than one extension with `os.rename()`.

As an example, if we had files `image.jpg`, `image.json`, `image2.jpg`, `image2.json` in a directory, we want to rename these files to `1.jpg`, `1.json`, `2.jpg`, `2.json`.

**Demo:**

```
from os import rename
from os import listdir

from os.path import splitext
from os.path import join

from collections import defaultdict

def rename_same_name_files(path):
    filenames = defaultdict(list)

    # Group each name with extensions
    for file in listdir(path):
        name, ext = splitext(file)
        filenames[join(path, name)].append(ext)

    # Enumerate starting from 1 over each name : [extensions] grouping
    for idx, (name, extensions) in enumerate(filenames.items(), start=1):

        # Only rename files with more than one extension found
        if len(extensions) > 1:

            # Go through each extension
            for ext in extensions:

                # Get new path
                new_path = join(path, "%d%s" % (idx, ext))

                # Rename files
                rename(name + ext, new_path)

rename_same_name_files("PATH\TO\FILES")
```

Comment: Why not use the full filename as the dictionary key? That way you wouldn't need to join it back later on

Answer (score 1):

Try `os.scandir(directory)` with string splitting and list popping, kind of like

```
import os

def getFilename(file_with_extension):
    return file_with_extension.split('.')[:len(file_with_extension.split('.')-1]

def getExtension(file_with_extension):
    return '.'+file_with_extension.split('.')[len(file_with_extension.split('.')-1]

path = '/~'

files = os.scandir(path)    

n=0
old_name_without_extension=""
#Make sure it's sorted alphabetically so all similar files will be next to each other
files.sort()
while files:
   file = files.pop()
   name_without_extension = getFilename(file)
   extension = getExtension(file)
   if not old_name_without_extension == name_without_extension:
        n+=1
   old_name_without_extension = name_without_extension
   #Here copy your file with new filename using path, extension and desired naming scheme
```